# convert unicode data into malayalam using python (\u0d35 format)

Tags: python

I have been doing topic modeling for malayalam news article. The topics are generated in unicode format. The output is as follows:

```
u'0.021*"\u0d2a\u0d3f" + 0.021*"\u0d35\u0d3f\u0d36\u0d4d\u0d35\u0d02\u0d2d\u0d30\u0d28\u0d4d\u0d31\u0d46" + 0.021*"\u0d05\u0d26\u0d4d\u0d26\u0d47\u0d39\u0d02"'
```

I want to convert this into readable string. whenever it involves file operations it just show same string in the output file. But i want the result like:

```
0.021*"പി" + 0.021*"വിശ്വംഭരന്റെ" + 0.021*"അദ്ദേഹം"
```

into a file

Answer (score 0):

seems to work fine for me ... make sure the terminal you are printing to supports it (well dang that screenshot isnt as readable as id hoped... oh well if you click it its fine)
[image]

if you want to write it to a file you probably need to encode it to utf8

```
with open("some_file","wb") as f: 
    f.write(u'0.021*"\u0d2a\u0d3f" + 0.021*"\u0d35\u0d3f\u0d36\u0d4d\u0d35\u0d02\u0d2d\u0d30\u0d28\u0d4d\u0d31\u0d46" + 0.021*"\u0d05\u0d26\u0d4d\u0d26\u0d47\u0d39\u0d02"'.encode("utf-8"))
```